# How to visualize multiple categorical variables vs one continuous variable in R

Tags: r, statistics, data-visualization, data-science, data-analysis

Say the categorical variables are,

1. Do_you_smoke -> Yes/ No
2. Do_you_drink -> Yes/No
3. Do_you_exercise -> Yes/No

All 3 categorical variables(Do_you_smoke, Do_you_drink, Do_you_exercise) have 2 category Yes or No. Now I want to visualize all these categorical variables against one continuous variable say "income" **at once**. How do I visualize this using **R** ?

Comment: What type of plot do you want to come out with? What have you tried? What doesn't work?

Comment: **1** I want to come out with the plot which relates all 3 explanatory categorical variable with 1 continuous response variable. My search on internet only got me boxplot which relates one categorical variable with one continuous variable. **2** I have tried ggpairs() function of the GGally package but I could not interpret the result. **3** My try with ggpairs() for categorical variable did not give satisfactory result. It is also very likely that I did not use ggpairs() correctly for categorical variable. I want to know whether it is possible to use ggpairs() for this purpose properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always better to include a reproducible example of your data so that we can ensure any possible solutions work with your own data structure. However, from your description we should be able to recreate an example data set like this:

```r
set.seed(69)

df <- data.frame(income = runif(1000, 10000, 100000))
df$smoke    <- c("Yes", "No")[1 + rbinom(1000, 1, df$income/200000)]
df$drink    <- sample(c("Yes", "No"), 1000, TRUE)
df$exercise <- c("No", "Yes")[1 + rbinom(1000, 1, df$income/100000)]
```

So our data frame contains four columns: the income amount and either a "Yes" or a "No" for each of your three variables:

```
head(df)
#>     income smoke drink exercise
#> 1 57767.86   Yes    No      Yes
#> 2 79192.70   Yes   Yes      Yes
#> 3 68132.37    No    No       No
#> 4 87873.44   Yes    No       No
#> 5 43199.45   Yes   Yes       No
#> 6 88188.83    No   Yes      Yes
```

To plot this, we need to reshape the data. Since the incomes are all different, we can't get a percentage at each individual income level, so we will have to `cut` the income into bins. Let's do this by $10,000 bins. We then need to get the proportion of "Yes" for each variable in each income band. Finally, we want to put out data into long format, so that each proportion in each bin has its own row, labelled according to which of the three categorical variables it represents. We can then plot using ggplot.

We need to load a few libraries to help us:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(tidyr)
```

And now our code looks like this:

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(income_bracket = cut(income, breaks = 1:10 * 10000)) %>%
  group_by(income_bracket) %>%
  summarise(exercise = length(which(exercise == "Yes"))/n(),
            smoke = length(which(smoke == "Yes"))/n(),
            drink = length(which(drink == "Yes"))/n()) %>%
  mutate(income = paste(dollar(1:9 * 10000), 
                        dollar(2:10 * 10000), sep = " -\n")) %>%
  select(-income_bracket) %>%
  pivot_longer(1:3) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = income, y = value, group = name, colour = name)) +
  geom_line(size = 1.3) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent, limits = c(0, 1)) +
  labs(title = "Percentage of activities by income",
       y = "Percent", x = "Income bracket", color = "Do you...")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a mistake in **select(-income_bracket)** ? I tried to execute @AllanCameron code and I' am getting error message - _Error in select(., -income_bracket) : unused argument (-income_bracket)_. I' am using RStudio Version 1.3.1056 and R version 4.0.2

Comment: @Ullas try specifying `dplyr::select(-income_bracket)`